# Faster way to make a zeroed array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I create zeroed Arrays in Scala with
`(0 until Nrows).map (_ => 0).toArray` but is there anything faster ? `map` is slow.

I have the same question but with 1 instead of O, i.e. I also want to accelerate `(0 until Nrows).map (_ => 1).toArray`

Comment: You could use the [saddle library](http://saddle.github.io/doc/quickstart.html#mat) or the [breeze library](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart) but that depends on what you want to do with this array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zero is the default value for an array of Ints, so just do this:

```
    val array = new Array[Int](NRows)
```

If you want all those values to be 1s then use .fill() (with thanks to @gourlaysama):

```
    val array = Array.fill(NRows)(1)
```

However, looking at how this works internally, it involves the creation of a few objects that you don't need. I suspect the following (uglier) approach may be quicker if speed is your main concern:

```
    val array = new Array[Int](NRows)
    for (i <- 0 until array.length) { array(i) = 1 }
```

Comment: To initialize an array with a value, you have the `Array.fill` method: `val array = Array.fill(NRows)(1)`, rather than iterating by hand.

Answer (score 6):

For multidimensional arrays consider `Array.ofDim`, for instance,

```
scala> val a = Array.ofDim[Int](3,3)
a: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0))
```

Likewise,

```
scala> val a = Array.ofDim[Int](3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0)
```

In the context here,

```
val a = Array.ofDim[Int](NRows)
```

For setting (possibly nonzero) initial values, consider `Array.tabulate`, for instance,

```
scala> Array.tabulate(3,3)( (x,y) => 1)
res5: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 1, 1), Array(1, 1, 1), Array(1, 1, 1))

scala> Array.tabulate(3)( x => 1)
res18: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 1)
```